# Replacing a sympy matrix symbol in a sum of its elements

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

Consider an arbitrary expression which contains a sum of elements of a Matrix symbol:

```py
>>> from sympy import MatrixSymbol
>>> A = MatrixSymbol('A',3,3)
>>> expr = A[1,2]+A[0,1]+A[2,0]
```

Is it possible to simply replace the matrix symbol `A`, with a numerical matrix `T`?

I assumed using `subs` would be sufficient, but this does not seem to be the case.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> T = np.arange(9).reshape((3,3))
>>> print(expr.subs(A,T))
A[0, 1] + A[1, 2] + A[2, 0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using a numpy array rather than a SymPy Matrix:

```
In [9]: from sympy import Matrix

In [10]: T = Matrix(np.arange(9).reshape(3, 3))

In [11]: expr
Out[11]: A₀₁ + A₁₂ + A₂₀

In [12]: expr.subs(A, T)
Out[12]: 12
```

Comment: Is there a way to deal with an NDim array instead of a Matrix?